# Bordered minor and rank of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let $M\in\mathbf{R}^{n\times n}$ be a matrix. Suppose that there is a  $k\times k$ minor  $M_k$ of rank k. Now this reference (Algebra For Iit Jee 7.65)  [here](http://books.google.de/books?id=Jp51spL2JOoC&pg=SA7-PA65&lpg=SA7-PA65&dq=bordered+minor+matrix+rank&source=bl&ots=drrD2xqO78&sig=XehAYB4wBQs96f-Uuldls4smUpw&hl=de&sa=X&ei=zf0sVPLbOM7jO__UgdgB&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=bordered%20minor%20matrix%20rank&f=false) states that if all the $k+1$th minors bordering the minor $M_k$ vanish this implies that the rank of $M$ is in fact $k$. Is this obvious? And if so, what exactly is a bordering minor?

Comment: It is not clear what is meant by 'bordering minor'. Your reference does not seem to give the pages where the determinant is first introduced. It is not obvious why one should only consider the 'bordering minors' as opposed to all $s\times s$ minors where $k<s<n$ unless bordering minor of a $l\times l$ minor is by definition any l+1\times l+1$ Minor.

Comment: Exactly. That is my main problem. I do not get the definition. The example that the book then gives seems to indicate however, that it is not any $l/times l$ minor

Comment: Not obvious but still true.

Comment: It is well known that the rank of a matrix $A$ over a field is equal to the largest integer $t$ such that $A$ contains a $t\times t$ sub matrix whose determinant is nonzero. So one can take this as the definition or rank of $A$ (instead of the one to do with row echelon form).

Comment: @Any: Ok, I agree with your definition: So having a $l\tims l$ minor that does not vanishes gives rank $M$ at least $l$. What still do not get is why it is sufficient to only check the "bordering" minors in oder to conclude that all bigger minors vanish.

Comment: @Orageskid: So any comment on to why it is true would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what a "bordering minor" is.
This does not seem to be a word with a standard meaning. However, here is a
theorem that is true:

**Theorem 1.** Let $\mathbf{k}$ be a field. Let $A\in\mathbf{k}^{u\times v}$
be a matrix. In the following, whenever $i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{k}\in\left\{
1,2,\ldots,u\right\}  $ and $j_{1},j_{2},\ldots,j_{\ell}\in\left\{
1,2,\ldots,v\right\}  $, we shall denote by $A\left[  \dfrac{j_{1}
,j_{2},\ldots,j_{\ell}}{i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{k}}\right]  $ the $k\times\ell
$-matrix whose $\left(  p,q\right)  $-th entry is the $\left(  i_{p}
,j_{q}\right)  $-th entry of $A$ for every $\left(  p,q\right)  \in\left\{
1,2,\ldots,k\right\}  \times\left\{  1,2,\ldots,\ell\right\}  $.

Let $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{k}\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots
,u\right\}  $ and $j_{1},j_{2},\ldots,j_{k}\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,v\right\}  $
be such that $\det\left(  A\left[  \dfrac{j_{1},j_{2},\ldots,j_{k}}
{i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{k}}\right]  \right)  \neq0$. Assume that every
$i^{\prime}\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,u\right\}  \setminus\left\{  i_{1}
,i_{2},\ldots,i_{k}\right\}  $ and $j^{\prime}\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots
,v\right\}  \setminus\left\{  j_{1},j_{2},\ldots,j_{k}\right\}  $ satisfy

**(1)** $\det\left(  A\left[  \dfrac{j_{1},j_{2},\ldots,j_{k},j^{\prime}
}{i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{k},i^{\prime}}\right]  \right)  =0$.

Then, $\operatorname*{rank}A=k$.

*Proof.* Assume the contrary; i.e., assume that $\operatorname*{rank}A\neq k$.

First, we observe that the numbers $i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{k}$ are distinct
(because otherwise, the matrix $A\left[  \dfrac{j_{1},j_{2},\ldots,j_{k}
}{i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{k}}\right]  $ would have two equal rows, which would
yield $\det\left(  A\left[  \dfrac{j_{1},j_{2},\ldots,j_{k}}{i_{1}
,i_{2},\ldots,i_{k}}\right]  \right)  =0$, contradicting $\det\left(  A\left[
\dfrac{j_{1},j_{2},\ldots,j_{k}}{i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{k}}\right]  \right)
\neq0$). Similarly, the numbers $j_{1},j_{2},\ldots,j_{k}$ are distinct.

The rows of the matrix $A\left[  \dfrac{j_{1},j_{2},\ldots,j_{k}}{i_{1}
,i_{2},\ldots,i_{k}}\right]  $ are linearly independent (since $\det\left(
A\left[  \dfrac{j_{1},j_{2},\ldots,j_{k}}{i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{k}}\right]
\right)  \neq0$). Hence, the rows of the matrix $A\left[  \dfrac{1,2,\ldots
,v}{i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{k}}\right]  $ are also linearly independent (since
the rows of the matrix $A\left[  \dfrac{j_{1},j_{2},\ldots,j_{k}}{i_{1}
,i_{2},\ldots,i_{k}}\right]  $ are fragments of the rows of the matrix
$A\left[  \dfrac{1,2,\ldots,v}{i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{k}}\right]  $, and
therefore any linear dependence relation between the latter would yield a
linear dependence relation between the former). In other
words, the $i_{1}$-th, the $i_{2}$-th, etc., the $i_{k}$-th rows of the matrix
$A$ are linearly independent. Hence, the matrix $A$ has $k$ linearly
independent rows; thus, $\operatorname*{rank}A\geq k$. Combined with
$\operatorname*{rank}A\neq k$, this yields $\operatorname*{rank}A>k$. Thus,
the row space of $A$ cannot be spanned by just $k$ of its rows (because if it
could, then its dimension would be $\leq k$, which would contradict the fact
that its dimension is $\operatorname*{rank}A>k$). Therefore, there exists at
least one $i^{\prime}\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,u\right\}  \setminus\left\{
i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{k}\right\}  $ such that the $i^{\prime}$-th row of $A$
does not belong to the span of the $i_{1}$-th, the $i_{2}$-th, etc., the
$i_{k}$-th rows of $A$. Fix such an $i^{\prime}$. We know that:

- The $i^{\prime}$-th row of $A$ does not belong to the span of the $i_{1}
  $-th, the $i_{2}$-th, etc., the $i_{k}$-th rows of $A$.
- The $i_{1}$-th, the $i_{2}$-th, etc., the $i_{k}$-th rows of $A$ are
  linearly independent.

Combining these two facts, we conclude that $i_{1}$-th, the $i_{2}$-th, etc.,
the $i_{k}$-th, and the $i^{\prime}$-th rows of $A$ are linearly independent.
In other words, the rows of the matrix $A\left[  \dfrac{1,2,\ldots,v}
{i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{k},i^{\prime}}\right]  $ are linearly independent.
Since this matrix has $k+1$ rows, we thus conclude that $\operatorname*{rank}
\left(  A\left[  \dfrac{1,2,\ldots,v}{i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{k},i^{\prime}
}\right]  \right)  =k+1>k$. Therefore, the column space of $A\left[
\dfrac{1,2,\ldots,v}{i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{k},i^{\prime}}\right]  $ cannot be
spanned by just $k$ of its columns (since if it could, then its dimension
would be $\leq k$, which would contradict the observation that its dimension
is $\operatorname*{rank}\left(  A\left[  \dfrac{1,2,\ldots,v}{i_{1}
,i_{2},\ldots,i_{k},i^{\prime}}\right]  \right)  >k$). Thus, there exists at
least one $j^{\prime}\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,v\right\}  \setminus\left\{
j_{1},j_{2},\ldots,j_{k}\right\}  $ such that the $j^{\prime}$-th column of
$A\left[  \dfrac{1,2,\ldots,v}{i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{k},i^{\prime}}\right]  $
does not belong to the span of the $j_{1}$-th, the $j_{2}$-th, etc., the
$j_{k}$-th columns of $A\left[  \dfrac{1,2,\ldots,v}{i_{1},i_{2},\ldots
,i_{k},i^{\prime}}\right]  $. Fix such a $j^{\prime}$.

On the other hand, the columns of the matrix $A\left[  \dfrac{j_{1}
,j_{2},\ldots,j_{k}}{i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{k}}\right]  $ are linearly
independent (since $\det\left(  A\left[  \dfrac{j_{1},j_{2},\ldots,j_{k}
}{i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{k}}\right]  \right)  \neq0$). In other words, the
$j_{1}$-th, the $j_{2}$-th, etc., the $j_{k}$-th columns of the matrix
$A\left[  \dfrac{1,2,\ldots,v}{i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{k}}\right]  $ are
linearly independent. Therefore, the $j_{1}$-th, the $j_{2}$-th, etc., the
$j_{k}$-th columns of $A\left[  \dfrac{1,2,\ldots,v}{i_{1},i_{2},\ldots
,i_{k},i^{\prime}}\right]  $ are linearly independent (because the $j_{1}$-th,
the $j_{2}$-th, etc., the $j_{k}$-th columns of the matrix $A\left[
\dfrac{1,2,\ldots,v}{i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{k}}\right]  $ are fragments of the
$j_{1}$-th, the $j_{2}$-th, etc., the $j_{k}$-th columns of $A\left[
\dfrac{1,2,\ldots,v}{i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{k},i^{\prime}}\right]  $, and
therefore any linear dependence relation between the latter would yield a
linear dependence relation between the former). Now we
know that:

- The $j^{\prime}$-th column of $A\left[  \dfrac{1,2,\ldots,v}{i_{1}
  ,i_{2},\ldots,i_{k},i^{\prime}}\right]  $ does not belong to the span of the
  $j_{1}$-th, the $j_{2}$-th, etc., the $j_{k}$-th columns of $A\left[
  \dfrac{1,2,\ldots,v}{i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{k},i^{\prime}}\right]  $.
- The $j_{1}$-th, the $j_{2}$-th, etc., the $j_{k}$-th columns of $A\left[
  \dfrac{1,2,\ldots,v}{i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{k},i^{\prime}}\right]  $ are
  linearly independent.

Combining these two facts, we conclude that the  $j_{1}$-th, the $j_{2}$-th,
etc., the $j_{k}$-th, and the $j^{\prime}$-th columns of $A\left[
\dfrac{1,2,\ldots,v}{i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{k},i^{\prime}}\right]  $ are
linearly independent. In other words, the columns of the matrix $A\left[
\dfrac{j_{1},j_{2},\ldots,j_{k},j^{\prime}}{i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{k}
,i^{\prime}}\right]  $ are linearly independent. Hence, $\det\left(  A\left[
\dfrac{j_{1},j_{2},\ldots,j_{k},j^{\prime}}{i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{k}
,i^{\prime}}\right]  \right)  \neq0$. But this contradicts **(1)**. Thus, we
have found a contradiction, and Theorem 1 is proven.